# Yesod form with multiple buttons

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a Yesod form for editing the contents of some static pages which are written using markdown (processed using Pandoc). I want to have two buttons - a 'preview' button which processes the markup and displays the result underneath the form, and a 'submit' button which saves the contents to the database.

What is the simplest way to do this with Yesod? All the form examples in the Yesod book have exactly one button. I've looked at the exposed functions / api, but I even if I add more than one submit button with different names and/or values to the form I can't figure out how to get Yesod to tell me which one was pressed.

Can anyone give me a simple example of a form with more than one button in Yesod, which trigger different actions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the Input form functions to get the raw values, and explicitly set a name attribute on the various buttons. Something like this in the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
```

And in the Haskell code:

```
res <- runFormPost ...
isPreview <- runInputPost $ iopt boolField "preview"
if isPreview then ... else ...
```

Sorry if this doesn't typecheck, I don't have my normal development system right now. But I think this is the right general approach.

Comment: I can't actually find runInputPost. In the latest version of yesod-form it's in Yesod.Form.Input. However, the latest version on hackage of Yesod is 0.8.2.1, and it depends on an older version of yesod-form, namely 0.1.*. Do I need to update to a newer version of Yesod to use this method? If so, when will the new version be on Hackage?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were on the beta version, my mistake. You can just use the equivalent functions from the current yesod-form, namely `runFormPost'` and `stringInput`. We're hopefully releasing the 0.9 release candidate tomorrow.

Comment: I've downloaded it, but I'm having problems. yesod-json depends on something called 'aeson-native' which isn't on hackage. Is it just aeson?

Comment: I also get other errors if I change 'aeson-native' to 'aeson'. For example, now I'm getting 'Yesod/Auth/Kerberos.hs:100:20: Not in scope: `html'' when compiling Yesod.Auth. I've looked at the modules it imports and can't find the 'html' it's referring to either. Are any of these build issues known?

Comment: Yes, you pulled at in incredibly unlucky time: I'd just merged a pull request and hadn't pushed fixes for it yet. I'm releasing the candidate within the next 12 hours hopefully, I'd recommend waiting till then.

Comment: @chrisdb, did you ever get this working? I get an error `Invalid Arguments` `Invalid boolean: Preview` displaying on the site containg the haskell code.

Comment: It isn't actually a boolean field. The field is a text field containing (IIRC) the name of the button. A value is only present if the button was pressed. Therefore, you do something like `iopt textField "preview"` and then if the value is Just something do one thing, and if it's Nothing do another.

Comment: http://lusku.de/blog/entry/1 seems to have an evolved answer to this - might be worth updating the answer here? [I'm no expert, so just suggesting this approach]