# Multiple button form cause invalid arguments error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to add another button to a working monadic get form, which triggers a different processing of the entire form (like preview and submit buttons commonly found in forum post forms).

So I tried to follow the advice from this answer to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051714/yesod-form-with-multiple-buttons):

First, adding another named input button:

```
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
```

Second, adding a call to runInputGet:

```
((res,widget),enc) <- runFormGet myform
isPreview <- runInputGet $ iopt boolField "preview"
... -- pre-processing the form input, i.e. basic error checks
case (isPreview,res') of
   (Just True, Just checkedRes) -> ... -- preview processing
   ( _       , Just checkedRes) -> ... -- proper processing
```

Unfortunately, it does not work: whenever I press my new button, I get an invalid arguments page, saying that there is an invalid boolean with the name attached to the second submit button.

A difference to the earlier question is, that I am using a GET form instead of a POST from. However, it appears to me that I need to include the boolean field in the original form, but adding an optional boolean field with the same name in the original monadic form does not change anything at all:

```
 _ <- mopt boolField ((String.fromString "preview") { fsName = "preview" }) Nothing
```

(I do not know what to do with the result from this mopt, as I neither need the view (no additional form field should be shown to the user) nor the result (since this is what the additional runInputGet already provides for))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for [boolField](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/1.2.1.3/doc/html/src/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#boolField), you'll see that it has a strict requirement for the format that the value is supposed to be in. Instead, you probably want to use `textField`- which accepts anything- and then simply test if the value was present.